# Why is it that, when I dereference an array pointer, the resulting value is a pointer to the first element of the array, not the entire array object?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>

int num[3]={66,77,88};

int main()
{
    int(*pi)[3]=&num;
    std::cout<<*pi;
}
```

The result is an address instead of an array. What is the explanation behind this?

Comment: It is the entire array object. Since `cout` doesn't know how to print arrays, it gets converted to a pointer to the first element and printed as pointer.

Comment: tl;dr: that's the same thing. The pointer to the first element of an array and the pointer to the array itself are usually the same (just with different types)

Comment: `&num` is a pointer to the array `num`. And you define `pi` as a pointer to an array of three `int` elements. What else did you expect? Did you want to make a *copy* of the `num` array?

Comment: Also note that for any array or pointer `pi` and index `i` the expression `pi[i]` is exactly equal to `*(pi + i)`. Now if we use index `0` then that's `pi[0]` which is equal to `*(pi + 0)` which is equal to `*(pi)` which is equal to `*pi`. And since `pi` is a pointer to an array `pi[0]` is the array itself, and as any array it can decay to a pointer to its first element which is what happens here: `*pi` will decay to `&num[0]`. And it's that pointer that's being printed.

Answer (score 18):

> not the entire array object?

`*pi` gives the array, i.e. the `int[3]`. But `operator<<` for `std::basic_ostream` doesn't have overloads taking array but has an [overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) taking pointer (`const void*`), then [array-to-pointer decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay) happens, the converted pointer (`int*`) is pointing to the 1st element of the array and then is converted to `const void*`, then is passed to `std::cout` and gets printed out.

> There is an implicit conversion from lvalues and rvalues of array type to rvalues of pointer type: it constructs a pointer to the first element of an array. This conversion is used whenever arrays appear in context where arrays are not expected, but pointers are:

Comment: See [C++ Standard - Latest Draft \[conv.array\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.array)

Comment: I have found a less formal phrasing works too: "Arrays in C are fickle creatures.  They decay into pointers if you look at them funny."

Answer (score 4):

Just like cout cannot print a vector, it cannot print an array. However cout will print the address of the first element.

If you take a look at the source code of iostream they mention cout as a pointer https://code.woboq.org/llvm/libcxx/src/iostream.cpp.html, and that is also why you always need to iterate over each item of your array as oppose to other languages (like Rust) where you can print a vector or an array.

For string there is an exception since in C and C++ they are (or should be!) NULL terminated, and that is why the whole char array is printed. But 0 is a valid number, hence there is no way to know the bounds of an int array unless you can detect it at compile time (which Rust does).

Answer (score 4):

When an array such as `int[3]` is printed, it is passed to a function whose signature in principle takes the array as an argument. It could be any of

```
   ostream & operator <<(ostream &s, int *value);
   ostream & operator <<(ostream &s, int value[]);
   ostream & operator <<(ostream &s, int value[3]);
```

However, in C/C++ these are all equivalent to the first one. Passing an array as argument to a function just passes a pointer to the beginning of the array. Therefore, the size of the array is not (directly) known to the function.

If we consider a `vector` instead of an array, then the `vector` object itself knows its size and we can print the vector. There is no built-in method for this, so we would have to make one ourselves (in this case just for a vector of `int` to illustrate the idea):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &s, const std::vector<int> &v)
{
    s << "(";
    for(auto &e: v)
    {
        if(&e != &v[0])
        {
            s << ", ";
        }
        s << e;
    }
    s << ")";
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> num = {66, 77, 88};
    std::cout << num;
}
```

The result is:

```
    (66, 77, 88)
```

Answer (score 2):

It’s not something I would normally recommend, but, if you define an override of `operator<<( ostream&, const int[3] )`, the compiler will run that, instead of decaying the array pointer to `void*` or something else.

Here’s some sample code that demonstrates how C++ implicitly converts the right-hand side of `operator<<`.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using std::ostream;
using std::ptrdiff_t;

template <ptrdiff_t N>
  ostream& operator<< ( ostream& out, const int (&a)[N] )
  {
    if constexpr (N > 1) {
      out << a[0];
      out << ", ";
      return ( out << *(const int(*)[N-1])(&(a[1])) );
    } else if constexpr (N == 1) {
      out << a[0];
    }

    return out;
  }

constexpr int nums[] = { 66, 77, 88 };
constexpr char letters[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 0 };
constexpr float reals[] = { 1.23f, 4.56f, 7.89f };

int main()
{
    std::cout << nums << '\n';
    static const int (*const pi)[3] = &nums;
    std::cout << *pi << std::endl;

    std::cout << (const char*)letters << '\n';
    std::cout << letters << std::endl;

    std::cout << (const void*)reals << '\n';
    std::cout << reals << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

(You could certainly quibble with the implementation.)

If you provide an overload that exactly matches `const int[3]`, it calls that.  With a `const char[4]`, the compiler tries decaying to a pointer of the element type, so the best match the compiler finds is `const char*`.  When there is no match for `const float[3]` or `const float*`, the array decays to a `const float*` and implicitly converts to a `void*`.