# Checksum function on STM32

Tags: c, stm32

I'm trying to make a function to calculate the checksum of an array. I should add all values in the array and take two's complement.
I've tested my code and the result is correct.
As soon as i try to implement this code in a separate function the result is wrong.
Can somebody help me solve this issue.

The function call is:

```
  uint8_t Testframe[] = {0xAA,0x43,0x10,0x97,0x55,0xBE, 0x6A, 0xEA, 0xF3, 0xBE, 0xF4, 0x71, 0x9D, 0xB2, 0x4B, 0x0B, 0x45, 0x56, 0x55};

  uint8_t result2 = 0;
  result2 = CalculateChecksum(Testframe);
```

The function is:

```
uint8_t CalculateChecksum( uint8_t array[])
{
uint64_t result = 0;
uint8_t  output = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++)
{
    result = result + array[i];
}
output = (uint8_t) result;
output = output ^ 0xFF;
output = output + 0x01;
return output;

}
```

The result should be 0x5A

Comment: `sizeof(array)` does _not_ give you the length of the array. You have to pass in the length of the array in a separate parameter.

Comment: You may also have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66865533/why-is-it-that-when-i-dereference-an-array-pointer-the-resulting-value-is-a-po

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on whether you are using 32 or 64 bit addressing, your `for` loop is only iterating `4` or `8` times, not the required `19` times.

This is because [Arrays in C always decay into a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) when passed as a function argument.
The following statement:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++)
```

Should have resulted in a compiler warning.  I see this one on my system:

*"  23, 30    warning: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') instead of 'uint8_t []'
"*

Which is basically saying `sizeof(array)`, once `array` has been passed as a function parameter, will yield the `sizeof` a pointer, not the `sizeof` the array itself, resulting in the wrong number of iterations.

Passing another parameter in your prototype is one way to address this.  eg:

```
uint8_t CalculateChecksum( uint8_t array[], size_t size);
```

Allowing the function to use a value representing the count of elements in array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{ ...
```

Calling example:

```
  size_t size = sizeof Testframe/sizeof Testframe[0];//provides number of elements in array
  result2 = CalculateChecksum(Testframe, size);
```

Finally, if you do not already have your compiler set to show warnings, change it to do so.  (eg `-Wall` if using GCC)